# Laravel Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, relationship

I have a problem when access relationship. Below the syntax:

```
$student = \App\StudentRegistrars::find($id);

        foreach($student->father_registrars as $getFatherData) {
            $fatherID = $getFatherData->id;
            $specificFather = \App\FatherRegistrars::where('id', $fatherID);
            $specificFather->update(['status' => 'Pending']);

            //count qualified students who have father with id $fatherID
            //problem lays here
            $getSelectedStudent = \App\StudentRegistrars::where('status', 'Qualified')->whereHas('father_registrars', function($q) use($fatherID) {
                $q->where('id', $fatherID);
            })->count();
            if($getSelectedFather == 1) {
                $fatherUsername = $getFatherData->username;
                $fatherCredential = \App\User::where('username', $fatherUsername);
                if($fatherCredential) {
                    $fatherCredential->forceDelete(); 
                }
            }
        }
```

**FatherRegistrars**

```
public function student_registrars(){ 
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\StudentRegistrars')->withTrashed();
    }
```

**StudentRegistrars**

```
public function father_registrars(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\FatherRegistrars')->withTrashed(); 
    }
```

**User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{ 
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles; //spatie
    use SoftDeletes; //trash user

    /** 
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'gender', 'phone', 'email', 'password',
    ]; 

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

As you see above, the problem is coming up when I've tried to count qualified students who have father with id `$fatherID`! I can't delete specific record in `users` table. It show me error:
Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `student_registrars` where `status` = Qualified and exists (select * from `father_registrars` inner join `father_registrars_student_registrars` on `father_registrars`.`id` = `father_registrars_student_registrars`.`father_registrars_id` where `student_registrars`.`id` = `father_registrars_student_registrars`.`student_registrars_id` and `id` = 137) and `student_registrars`.`deleted_at` is null)

**UPDATE:**
I will explain more clear about this case. I mean, there is parent with his two child, as you see in the image below:
[image: image1]
And when I hit button "Qualified", it will generate account in `users` table automatically, as you see in the image below:
[image: users table]
Everything is okey until here.

But the problem is coming up when I hit "Hold Back" button. Something I want in this case is, when parents still **has more than one** qualified children in `users` table, system cannot delete parents in `users` table. Otherwise, when I hit "Hold Back" button, data parents in `users` table will be deleted automatically if parents **only has one** qualified childern.

Comment: What is the output of `$fatherUsername`?

Comment: I haven't check the input yet. Can you tell me how to check? The only result I got was, it can't delete specific record in `users` table.

Comment: depending on where this code is, you should be able to get the value by doing `dd($fatherUsername);`

Comment: Write your models attributes: `StudentRegistrars`, `FatherRegistrars`, `User`. I think you don't have username in `FatherRegistrars`. It should have a relation to user and you have to delete it via relationships.

Comment: `dd($fatherUsername);` was added below code `$fatherUsername = $getFatherData->username;` but nothing happens

Comment: I've updated the code. Please check!

Comment: I've updated the code with a clear case and explanation, also I've attached a picture to be more clear. Please check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//count qualified students who have father with id $fatherID
//problem lays here
$getSelectedStudent = \App\StudentRegistrars::where('status', 'Qualified')->whereHas('father_registrars', function($q) use($fatherID) {
                $q->where('id', $fatherID);
            })->count();
```

In `$q->where('id', $fatherID);` here **'id'** is ambiguous because in your join query both `father_registrars` and `student_registrars` table have same column **id** .So in your case where condition without table name is the cause of ambiguous. Specify the table name with the column will solve your problem.

So in your case, your query should be like this.

```
$getSelectedStudent = \App\StudentRegistrars::where('status', 'Qualified')->whereHas('father_registrars', function($q) use($fatherID) {
                    $q->where('father_registrars.id', $fatherID);
                })->count();
```

Comment: Thanks man! That's works like a charm. Many thanks for you!

Comment: Hi man, can you please answer my another question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62607253/laravel-count-multiple-selected-data-who-has-relationship

Answer (score 0):

Inside the first foreach loop you are doing...

```
$specificFather = \App\FatherRegistrars::where('id', $fatherID);
```

when you should do something like...

```
$specificFather = \App\FatherRegistrars::where('id', $fatherID)->first();
```

OR

```
$specificFather = \App\FatherRegistrars::findOrFail($fatherID);
```

Also in second foreach do...

```
$fatherCredential = \App\User::where('username', $fatherUsername)->first();
```

Comment: Please explain in your answer why this is better.

Comment: Because, Model::where() only returns Eloquent Builder Instance, not the actual object you need to access the needed properties.

Comment: I've updated the code with a clear case and explanation, also I've attached a picture to be more clear. Please check it out!