# Laravel Count Multiple Selected Data Who Has Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, relationship

I have a problem when access data who has relationship. Below this syntax is work properly:

```
$student = \App\StudentRegistrars::find($id);

        foreach($student->father_registrars as $getFatherData) {
            $fatherID = $getFatherData->id;
            $specificFather = \App\FatherRegistrars::where('id', $fatherID);
            $specificFather->update(['status' => 'Pending']);

            //count qualified students who have father with id $fatherID
            $getSelectedStudent = \App\StudentRegistrars::where('status', 'Qualified')->whereHas('father_registrars', function($q) use($fatherID) {
                $q->where('father_registrars.id', $fatherID);
            })->count();
            if($getSelectedFather == 1) {
                $fatherUsername = $getFatherData->username;
                $fatherCredential = \App\User::where('username', $fatherUsername);
                if($fatherCredential) {
                    $fatherCredential->forceDelete(); 
                }
            }
        }
```

**FatherRegistrars**

```
public function student_registrars(){ 
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\StudentRegistrars')->withTrashed();
    }
```

**StudentRegistrars**

```
public function father_registrars(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\FatherRegistrars')->withTrashed(); 
    }
```

**User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{ 
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles; //spatie
    use SoftDeletes; //trash user

    /** 
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'gender', 'phone', 'email', 'password',
    ]; 

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

As you see above, there is no problem when I've tried to count qualified students who have father with id `$fatherID`! I can delete specific record in `users` table.

But when I change the code above to the code below, it can't do multiple delete specific record in `users` table:

```
$get_ids = $request->ids;
$ids = explode(',', $get_ids); 

//count selected qualified students (whereIn('id', $ids)) who have father with id $fatherID
        $fatherUsername = \App\FatherRegistrars::select('username')->whereHas('student_registrars', function($q) use($ids) {
            $q->whereIn('student_registrars.id', $ids);
        })->get();
        $fatherID = \App\FatherRegistrars::select('id')->whereHas('student_registrars', function($q) use($ids) {
            $q->whereIn('student_registrars.id', $ids);
        })->get();
//problem lays here
        $getQualifiedFatherStudent = \App\StudentRegistrars::where('status', 'Qualified')->whereHas('father_registrars', function($q) use($fatherID) {
            $q->whereIn('father_registrars.id', $fatherID);
        })->count();

if($getQualifiedFatherStudent == 1) {
            $fatherCredential = \App\User::whereIn('username', $fatherUsername);
            if($fatherCredential) {
                $fatherCredential->forceDelete(); 
            } 
        }
```

This is realtionship between student registrars and father registrars table:
[image]

[**CODE UPDATED**]
I've updated the code below, yes the code is work, but a little, it's work only on certain case, but with another case, it's doesn't work.

```
$get_ids = $request->ids;
$ids = explode(',', $get_ids); 

$students = \App\StudentRegistrars::whereIn('id', $ids);
$students->update(['status' => 'Pending']); 

$fatherUsername = \App\FatherRegistrars::select('username')->whereHas('student_registrars', function($q) use($ids) {
    $q->whereIn('student_registrars.id', $ids);
})->get();
$getQualifiedFatherStudent = \App\FatherRegistrars::where('username', $fatherUsername)->whereHas('student_registrars', function($q) {
    $q->where('student_registrars.status', 'Qualified');
}); 

foreach($getQualifiedFatherStudent as $eachResult) {
            $getCount = $eachResult->count();
            if($getCount == 0) {
                $fatherCredential = \App\User::whereIn('username', $fatherUsername);
                if($fatherCredential) {
                    $fatherCredential->forceDelete(); 
                } 
            }
}
```

Something I want is:
when parents still at least has one qualified children, system cannot delete the parents in users table. Otherwise, if parents doesn't have any qualified childern, the parents in `users` table will be deleted too.

For more clear, you can see the image below:
[image]
As you see in this image below, Sugeng Handoyo as a father has two qualified childern, John Doe and Dave Johnson. And james Brian as a father has only one qualified childern, Diana Esmeralda. I want to delete (Hold Back) these two.

Refer to my rule, when parents still at least has one qualified children, system cannot delete the parents in users table. Otherwise, if parents doesn't have any qualified childern, the parents in `users` table will be deleted too.
But I got unexpected result below:
[image]
As you see above, James Brian should be deleted from that list, becuase his qualified childern has been deleted, but he is still exist.

Comment: I guess you make a little mistakes with the relationship between `student_registrars` and `father_registrars` table. Could you let me know the relationship between  `student_registrars` and `father_registrars` table.

Comment: The relationship between student_registrars and father_registrars table is added, please check it!

Comment: Well, did you get any errors? and could you print the `$fatherCredential` value?

Comment: The error I got is, whenever I try to do multiple delete, it will end with failure. I don't know why. 

The only one problem is in `$getQualifiedFatherStudent`. When I remove this code, the rest code is work. I mean, it can delete specific record in `users` table

Comment: `$getSelectedStudent = \App\StudentRegistrars::where('status', 'Qualified')->whereHas('father_registrars', function($q) use($fatherID) {
                $q->where('father_registrars.id', $fatherID);
            })->count();
`

and 
`$getQualifiedFatherStudent = \App\StudentRegistrars::where('status', 'Qualified')->whereHas('father_registrars', function($q) use($fatherID) {
            $q->whereIn('father_registrars.id', $fatherID);
        })->count();
`
is same. so where is the problem I could not understand.

Comment: the problem is code `$getQualifiedFatherStudent` is not working at all when I do bulk delete. But when I do single delete, it works!

Comment: Could you print the `$getQualifiedFatherStudent`

Comment: Can you show me how can I print that? Still thinking to do this

Comment: dd($getQualifiedFatherStudent);

Comment: I have 4 data, and it show me 4, even I've deleted the data... Seems the computer count selected the data first, and then delete the data. Supposed delete the selected data first, and then count the result

Comment: run the this query
`$getQualifiedFatherStudent = \App\StudentRegistrars::where('status', 'Qualified')->whereHas('father_registrars', function($q) use($fatherID) {
            $q->whereIn('father_registrars.id', $fatherID);
        })->toSql();`

 it will return the SQL which you are trying to execute. Then find out the problem from query.

Comment: This is when I do bulk action:
select * from `student_registrars` where `status` = ? and exists (select * from `father_registrars` inner join `father_registrars_student_registrars` on `father_registrars`.`id` = `father_registrars_student_registrars`.`father_registrars_id` where `student_registrars`.`id` = `father_registrars_student_registrars`.`student_registrars_id` and `father_registrars`.`id` in (?, ?, ?))

Comment: I've updated the code with better explanation. Please take a look! Help me please... Got stuck in this problem for a days.

Comment: can you try this query 
`$getQualifiedFatherStudent = \App\FatherRegistrars::where('username', $fatherUsername)->doesntHave('student_registrars', function($q) {
    $q->where('student_registrars.status', 'Qualified');
}); `

I think it will return you all unqualified student fathers which you are trying to delete. If father have at least one qualified student it will not return that father.

Comment: still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216929/discussion-between-ashraf789-and-sead-lab).